# c# add object to list via its constructor

Tags: c#, oop

Just because of interest ...

Given I have a statically defined `List<Car> CarsList`, and an object of type `Car`, can I instantiate a new car and add it to the list, while getting a reference to it, in a one-liner?

If I instantiate a car like `c1 = new Car("Honda Civic")`, it seems I cannot add the car to the list in its constructor:

```cs
public Car (string name) {
    _name = name;
    CarsList.add(this);  // adds null
}
```

And it seems that I can not do it the other way round either:

```cs
c1 = CarsList.add(new Car("Honda Civic"));  // does not work, list.add does not return a reference to the newly added object.
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you put the real code pls. This code can't be even compiled

Comment: Q should contain all required infos. Complete code is waste of time.

Comment: `Car c; CarsList.Add(c = new Car());`?

Comment: I knew there must be an easy way, thanks!

Comment: Although I don't see what's wrong with `CarsList.Add(this);`, that also [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HsB38d).

Comment: I get a System.NullReferenceException. Seems I need to pull together a code sample after lunch ... given you are sure.

Comment: I have pulled it together, click the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, after having a great lunch and going through all this again I found my error. Silly me. CarsList was missing the = new(). The crash had nothing to do with using "this" in the constructor at all. I admit, you were perfectly right: if  I had taken the time to write a quick code sample, I would probably have seen the problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really wanted such a construct, I would add an extension method to `List<T>` which adds the item to the list and returns the item.  I would call that extension method `With()`.

That having been said, adding your `Car` to the `CarsList` from within the constructor of `Car` should ***not*** add `null`. You must be doing something fishy there.

Comment: You are right. CarsList was missing the = new(). The crash had nothing to do with using "this" in the constructor at all.